# iptables v1.4.7: option `state' requires an argument

Tags: iptables, centos6

Hi I'm trying to set IPTABLE rules and I get the error iptables v1.4.7: option `state' requires an argument when trying to issue.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

in a CentOS6 VPS

I would like to note I am also utilizing csf if maybe that could be why though I don't think so.

I'm trying to set up OpenVPN on CentOS

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaaCs.png

-- I hope this is what you meant MadHatter

Comment: I removed a wrong-format dash from your posting, which I assume is just a markup error.  But to be on the safe side, could you cut-and-paste an example of the problem into your **question**?

Comment: what ever you did to the formatting fixed it and it actually works now... from copy/pasting to over crt

Comment: Seems that you had an extra parasite character somewhere in your original command line...

Comment: yeah that must have been it thanks for the fix I dunno how to make this post answered i can't self answer my rep is to low.

Comment: You're welcome.  I've written my fix up as an answer, with a little more context, in case you want to accept that.  It would be a good idea to accept some kind of answer, to prevent this question floating around indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the image you've posted, it's clear that the two dashes aren't the same length; the second is longer (an "*em dash*", I believe they're called).  I don't know if that was done by cutting and pasting an instruction from a word-processed document, or in some other way, but Linux just wants two bog-standard, ordinary dashes.

I note that when you gave it two such dashes, that fixed matters.

I also note with interest that the error message produced by my `iptables` is `option "--state" must be specified`; note the difference between the simple repeated-double-quote style in that, and the "balanced" quotes that appear in your title and the first line of your post.

Whatever you're using to interact with the command line on Linux, it seems to want to apply word-processing tricks to your input, and that's going to cause you nothing but pain.  Backticks (such as the leading quote in ``state'`) in particular have a very specific function in`bash`, and it's nothing to do with quoting.  Find a better tool.